# run a test script 100 times in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

Currently I am using Selenium Webdriver, and for annotation I am using testNG, In my code I have 100 test scripts  with @test annotation ..I just want to run only one of my test case 100 times ..how I can  do it   any suggestion with proper example is much appreciated eg

run only script number 5 hundred times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `@Test` annotation - you can add a invocationCount attribute with the number of times you want to run it.

```
@Test(invocationCount = 100)
public void testMethod() {
}
```

Comment: yes, voted up, for documentation http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html . Thank You